# Different behaviour between Docker and docker-compose in Oracle DB image

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

In some project we're using this Docker image to do some PoC: https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-12c

The instructions say that you can put SQLs into the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder to load them on startup, so my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM sath89/oracle-12c
COPY */*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 8080 1521
```

Not much rocket science there. The SQL files are stored like this:

```
project/
├── init/
│   ├── 101-init.sql
│   ├── 102-sometables.sql
│   ├── 103-few-triggers.sql
│   └── 104-more-stuff.sql
├── masterdata/
│   ├── 201-some-inserts.sql
│   └── 202-more-inserts.sql
|
└── Dockerfile
```

My problem comes when I run it using a normal Docker command:
`docker run --name=my-oracle -d -v db:/u01/app/oracle:rw -p 1527:1521 -p 10000:8080 my-oracle`

Scripts are picked OK, but they're not executed in alphabetical order, so I get tons of errors.

Instead, if I run it from docker-compose, with this YML file, it works like a charm, everything is executed in order:

```
...
db:
    image: my-oracle
    container_name: my-oracle
    volumes:
     - ./db:/u01/app/oracle:rw
    ports:
     - 1527:1521
     - 10000:8080
    environment:
     - DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=1024
```

Honestly I'm completely lost on making a diagnosis of this. If this failed in both I'd have more clues, but I don't know why is this happening. Maybe my "alphabetical order" assumption is completely wrong. Also, putting everything on one single file of course could solve this issue, but I'd like to have everything separated by purpose/concern.

Could you give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just starting to play with Oracle on Docker, so I'm interested in this and am keen to know the answer. However, as a general observation, it seems like you should be using a build tool (Liquibase, Flyway., whatever) to run these scripts rather than relying on Docker to get it right.

Comment: Absolutely. How do you manager your database migrations outside of Docker?